# QT pixel position from image when mouse click

Tags: qt

I'm using QGraphicView and QGraphicScene to display and image. I would like to get image pixel coordinate when i mouse click on that pixel. For that i use mousePressEvent and implement function to isplay event position. But the problem is the image pixel position is wrong because i obtain the pixel coordinate corresponding to the GraphicView not the pixel coordinate in the image. I think it will gives me a right answer when the view have exactly the same size than the image (at least how to do that ?), but i preffer more sophisticated solution.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override the mouse press event for [QGraphicsPixmap](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qgraphicspixmapitem.html) item.

Comment: or install an scene event filter